# Tkz-euclide \tkzInterLC compilation issues

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am having some problems with tkz-Euclide. Using texlive-2019.20200218-1 on ubuntu 20.04.5. I try to compile the following example, from the documentation (tkz-Euclide 4.25.c)

I get an error pointing to `\tkzInterLC[near]` . I also tried some other examples, some give problems, some do not. Looks to me (but this is to be confirmed) that some commands involving circles give problems. Wljile point G is the one I expect, poit L is choosen at the antipode of the big circle.

I also tried to compile in Overleaf and in Cocalc, in both cases the output was not what is expected (I only tested for the very precise example below pn Overleaf or Cocalc, not for other examples from the documentation).

```
%% My preamble is slightly modified
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{physics}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\colorlet{veccol}{green!45!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!90!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!90!black}
\colorlet{mypurple}{blue!50!red!80!black!80}

\colorlet{input}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{output}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{triangle}{orange!40}
\colorlet{input}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{output}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{triangle}{orange!40}


\tikzstyle{vector}=[->,very thick,veccol]

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzstyle{thin arrow}=[dashed,thin,-{Latex[length=4,width=3]}]
\tikzstyle{line} = [thin, arsenic]
\tikzstyle{points} = [color = arsenic]

%% Now the example


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0.75,0.25){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1.5){C}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzInterLC[near](D,B)(B,C) \tkzGetSecondPoint{G}
\tkzInterLC[near](D,A)(D,G) \tkzGetFirstPoint{L}
\tkzDrawCircles(B,C D,G)
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 2](D,A D,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments[red](A,L B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[red](D,L,G)
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left,red](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right,red](L)
\tkzLabelCircle[above](B,C)(20){$\mathcal{(H)}$}
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](G)
\tkzLabelPoints[above,red](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right,red](B)
\tkzLabelCircle[below](D,G)(-90){$\mathcal{(K)}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It does seem that there is a small error, you must replace \tkzInterLC[near](D,A)(D,G) \tkzGetFirstPoint{L} by \tkzInterLC[near](D,A)(D,G) ) \tkzGetSecondPoint{L}

Comment: removing `[near]` took the error away.

Comment: Also, please clean your MWE and add document environment.

Comment: Thanks! combining your comments I do get what I need : on one hand the I need to use `\tkzGetSecondPoint{L}` to have to good point, and on the other hand I do need to remove the `[near]` option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load `TikZ` with `tkz-euclide`.

I think if you are using the texlive-2019 version of `tkz-euclide` then you cannot compile the examples from the latest version of `tkz-euclide`.

You can with the intersections that give several points used: ``tkzGetPoints{X}{Y}`and then you can choose the right one.

The options for intersections are new and only work with version 4.25

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(0.75,0.25){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,1.5){C}
  \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D}
  \tkzInterLC[near](D,B)(B,C) \tkzGetSecondPoint{G}
  \tkzInterLC[near](D,A)(D,G) \tkzGetFirstPoint{L}
  \tkzDrawCircles(B,C D,G)
  \tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 2](D,A D,B)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
  \tkzDrawSegments[red](A,L B,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints[red](D,L,G)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left,red](A)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below right,red](L)
  \tkzLabelCircle[above](B,C)(20){$\mathcal{(H)}$}
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](D)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](G)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above,red](C)
  \tkzLabelPoints[right,red](B)
  \tkzLabelCircle[below](D,G)(-90){$\mathcal{(K)}$}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in the doc p.23 the figure does not give the L in this position.

Comment: @pascal974 Yes you are right. The problem is discussed in the doc here D is the center of the circle (D,L) and `near` cannot work correctly unless you use (A,D) and not (D,A). This is an error I had not seen.